# How to get which pod that the client is using in my loadbalancer?

Tags: node.js, sockets, kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-pod

I deployed a kubernetes cluster and using 3 replicas for my backend NodeJS.

I am now applying some socket function and want to make sure my redis pub and sub function is working from different pod.

Therefore, I want to display the NodeJS pod name on client side to test whether is working.

*and I am using ReactJS as my frontend (client side)

Answer (score 2):

The server pod would have to put that in a header or otherwise purposefully send it down to the client.

Comment: The default hostname for pods running in Kubernetes is the pod name, which will give you a path to retrieve it.

Comment: That is one option, I would probably use a fieldRef environment variable to be a bit more explicit though :)